# if $f: X \rightarrow (0, \infty)$, then $\mu (A_n) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ be a measure space and let $A_n= \{x \in X: f(x) \leq 1/n \}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. I have shown that if $f: X \rightarrow (0, \infty)$, then $\mu (A_n) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ provided that $\mu (X) < \infty$. But what happens when $\mu(X) = \infty$? And what does it exactly means for a set to have an infinite positive measure?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ is  $(0,\infty)$ with Lebesgue measure and $f(x)=\frac 1 x$ then $\mu (A_n)=\infty$ for all $n$.

In general if you assume that $\mu(A_n) <\infty$ for some $n$ then you can conclude that $\mu(A_n) \to 0$. So we can say that either $\mu(A_n) \to 0$ or $\mu(A_n) =\infty$ for all $n$.

Comment: This works! Thank you so much!